# No reaction back or end

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a question in my program, which asks if a user want to go back to menu or they want to end the program.

First I had this code in the `back()` function, but then I moved it to code (out of `def`), because I thought there is something wrong with `def`. But it is still not working. The part of code I mean is selected between `#`.

```
while True:
    zoznam()

zam=input("\n   Nacitaj hodnotu zamestnanca: ")
time.sleep(.5)
clear()

if zam == "1":
    print("Zamestnanec: Ewo Salae")
    print("K výplate {} EUR.".format(PD))
    print("\n")
    desto = PD % 200
    desto2 = int((PD - desto)/200)
    print("200 EUR - {}".format(desto2))
    vyplata()
#
    bb = str(input("Vratit sa do zoznamu - Z\n Ukončiť program - U\n Vasa moznost: "))
    if bb == "U" or "u"():
        print("stop")
    if bb == "z" or "Z"():
        print("Návrat do menu")
#
```

The `def` looks:

```
def back():
    bb = str(input("Vratit sa do zoznamu - Z\n Ukončiť program - U\n Vasa moznost: "))
    if bb == "U" or "u":
        print("stop")
    if bb == "z" or "Z":
        print("Návrat do menu")
```

Comment: In your expression `bb == "z" or "Z"` (in the second `if` statement of the `back()` function) the part `"Z"` is always `True` (because non-empty strings are considered `True` in Python), and — consequently — the full expression is `True`, too. ([tgyger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11644920/tgyger) showed you in his answer how to correct it, I'm only adding this explanation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def back(): 
    bb = str(input("Vratit sa do zoznamu - Z\n Ukončiť program - U\n Vasa moznost: ")) 
    if bb == "U" or bb == "u": 
        print("stop") 
    if bb == "z" or bb == "Z":
        print("Návrat do menu")

back()
```

compare the variable after "or"

Comment: Please don't hesitate to upvote this answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: You can also do `if bb.lower() == "z"` to be more clear that you don't care about the letter case.